# Need help in understanding recursion in Chapter 10 of Learn to Program by Chris Pine

Tags: ruby

Questions:

1.)If the `world[y][x] != 'land'` condition is true, it will `return 0`. Who holds that value now? Are the codes after this `if-end statement` will still be evaluated?

2.)There are 8 `size = size + ...` lines, which represents 8 neighbors of the tile (5,5). So using (5,5) and using `size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y-1)` line, I know it will count (4,4) which in this case is `o`. My question, since (4,4) is `o` which is a `water`, will it still count (3,3), (2,2), etc or will it stop right after (4,4) and count the next `size = size + ...` line?

```
# These are just to make the map easier for me to read.
# "M" is visually more dense then "o".
M = 'land'
o = 'water'

world = [[o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o],
         [o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o,M,o],
         [o,o,o,M,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,o],
         [o,o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o],
         [o,M,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o]]

def continent_size world, x, y
  if world[y][x] != 'land'
    # Either it's water or we already counted it,
    # but either way, we don't want to count it now.
    return 0
  end

  # So first we count this tile...
  size = 1
  world[y][x] = 'counted land'

  # ...then we count all of the neighboring eight tiles
  # (and, of course, their neighbors by way of the recursion).
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x  , y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y-1)
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y  )
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y  ) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x-1, y+1) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x  , y+1) 
  size = size + continent_size(world, x+1, y+1) 
  size
end

puts continent_size(world, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The value 0 will be held by the one who called that function, let's say

```
a = continent_size(world, x, y)
```

now a is 0. The rest of the statements will not be evaluated because the return statement will end the execution of that method.

2) There is no return statement between the lines size = ... so it will execute all of them

Answer (score 0):

1) The 0 value will be returned to the `continent_size` metehod instace which invoked the instance you are asking about. The rest of the `if-end` statement will not be evaluated as the method already returns 0 to its caller.

2) It will 'stop' right after `(4,4)` (as it is water it will simply return `0`) and count the next `size = ...` line indeed